# Change Content of TabView Dynamically Cause Page to Become Blank

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-tabview

When I try to change the content of a `TabView` in runtime, the app crashes or show a blank screen. Platform: Xcode 15.0 beta 6 (15A5219j) / iOS 17.0 beta 5 (21A5303d)

Below is the minimal code that can reproduce this issue. Note that this code will run normally as expected on iOS 16.

```swift
import SwiftUI

class Coordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var open = false
}

struct TabbedView: View {
    @StateObject var coordinator = Coordinator()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            if coordinator.open {
                Text("Hello World!")
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Feature", systemImage: "star")
                    }
            }
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                }
        }
        .environmentObject(coordinator)
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var coordinator: Coordinator
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Button("Toggle") {
                    coordinator.open.toggle()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Settings")
        }
    }
}
```

The app has 2 sections: A blank *feature* section and a *settings* section. In the settings section, there is a button that can control whether the feature section should appear. When I tap the button for the first time, the feature section appears normally. However, when I tap the button for the second time, the feature section disappears, but all content within settings section disappears, the page just **become blank**.

The `NavigationStack` is crucial for the bug to appear. Did I do something wrong here, or is it a bug of SwiftUI?

Comment: You probably need to have the ```TabView``` inside the ```NavigationStack``` and not vice versa.

Comment: @Benzy Neez I intent to maintain different navigation stack in different sections, so that they can have independent navigation status. I believe this design is also used in native iOS apps, such as photo and music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of having a `NavigationStack` for every tab is the correct approach. specifies that the tabs should not share navigation in the Human Interface Guidelines.

You can solve your issue by "reserving" the spot with `EmptyView`.

```
struct TabbedView: View {
    @StateObject var coordinator = Coordinator()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            if coordinator.open {
                Text("Hello World!")
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Feature", systemImage: "star")
                    }
            } else { //"reserve" spot
                EmptyView()
            }
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                }
        }
        .environmentObject(coordinator)
    }
}
```

You should submit this as a bug though, hopefully apple will eventually fix these types of issues.

This is just a workaround, it may or may not work in certain versions.

A more reliable way is to redraw everything but it is very inefficient.

```
struct TabbedView: View {
    @StateObject var coordinator = Coordinator()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            if coordinator.open {
                Text("Hello World!")
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Feature", systemImage: "star")
                    }
            }
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                }
        }
        .id(coordinator.open) //Set an id
        .environmentObject(coordinator)
    }
}
```